# Loop For And Add To List

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to create a list of URL's `visit_urls` to visit.
at first I specify manually the first url to visit `self.br.get(url)`
and checking the amount of pages that the page has for example it has 40 pages, I will know that it with "count" and I just want to switch the end of the url with &page=2 &page=3 up to 40 in a list.

Here is the loop part of my code. I only need a way to add all the pages into the `visit_urls` list

```
visit_urls=[]
self.br.get(url)
count = self.br.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='count']").get_attribute("innerHTML"):
for (here up to count) 
    self.visit_urls.append(url + need to append this also to the end of the first url &page=2-count)
```

This code comes after a lot of research and I'm stuck so any help will be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
visit_urls=[]
self.br.get(url)
count = self.br.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='count']").get_attribute("innerHTML")

for page_number in xrange(1, count+1):
    url = '{url}&page={page_number}'.format(url=url, page_number=page_number)
    visit_urls.append(url)
```

This will work assuming `url` never changes. That is, if the `url` variable always points to the same url, you will end up with urls like `http://www.mysite.com&page=1&page=2&page=3`

Make sure url is always defined appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming everything works and the issue you're having is in generating an array of all URLs based on your findings in "count".

The easiest thing to do would be if you already know the URL, and it's in the proper format, such as:

```
url = 'http://www.thisisapage.com/somethinghere/dosomething.php?page=1'
```

If that's the case, do *something* to strip the 1, getting a 'baseurl' to act on (exactly how to do this depends on what urls, and how they are formed):

```
baseurl = 'http://www.thisisapage.com/somethinghere/dosomething.php?page='
```

After, just loop from n to count, appending the current iteration to the baseurl.

Often, it's a lot easier to use a regular expression to do this if you're ever going to have complex URLs, or dynamic URLs that may include security tokens and the such.

For that, you could use something like:

```
import re
m = re.match(r'^(.*)(page=\d+&?)(.*)$', url)

for i in range(2, count):
    self.visit_urls.append(m.group(1) + 'page=%i' % i + m.group(3))
```

Of course, since you're using a URL, that could be so many things, it will fall on you to make sure that the regular expression catches everything that it needs to.  Mine was very simple based on the information you provided.

Comment: you're right I do have the baseurl and it's without page= so I only need to append it from page=2 so I guess also need to make count-1 because the baseurl I will add it before the loop

Answer (score 0):

A very basic webcrawler in Python:

```
import re, urllib 

print "Enter the URL you wish to crawl.." # 
print 'Usage  - "http://example.com/"'
myurl = input("@> ")
for i in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.urlopen(myurl).read(), re.I): 
    for ee in re.findall('''href=["'](.[^"']+)["']''', urllib.urlopen(i).read(), re.I):
            print ee
```

Comment: I don't really need the way to visit it only the loop part is what I need It's selenium and I have all the other code ready just trying to get it clean into the list :)